# React Unit Test Cases for connected components: shallow method is empty

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I'm stuck where initially I was facing an error when I tried using the `configureStore` from 'redux-mock-store', I got an error of `Cannot find module 'redux-mock-store'`, even though I had added it in my **package.json**. So, in turn I tried to not use it and instead, do this:

**testComponent.spec.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { TestComponent } from './TestComponent';

describe('Test Component', () => {
  let [methodOne,methodTwo] = new Array(2).fill(jest.fn());
  const store = {
    subscribe: () => {},
    dispatch: () => {},
    getState: () => ({
      contactDetail: {
        email: 'abc.xyz@gmail.com',
        age: 25
      },
      contact: {
        firstName: 'abc',
        lastName: 'xyz'
      },
      showVal: { isEnabled: false },
      methodOne: methodOne,
      methodTwo: methodTwo
    })
  };

  it('should test if the component exists', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <TestComponent />
      </Provider>,
      { context: { store }, childContextTypes: { store: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any) } }
    );

    const exists = wrapper.exists('wrapper-class');
    expect(exists).toBe(true);
  });
}
```

**TestComponent.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
.... some more imports ....

function TestComponent(props) {
  const [methodOne, methodTwo, isEnabled, contactDetail] = props;
  return ( 
    contactDetail && contactDetail.email &&
    <div className="wrapper-class">
      .... Some Code ....
    </div>
}

TestComponent.propTypes = {
  methodOne: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  methodTwo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  showVal: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  contact: PropTypes.objectOf(any).isRequired
};

export default connect(
  state => {
    const {
      contactDetail,
      contact,
      showVal: { isEnabled }
    } = state;
      return { ...contactDetail, contact, isEnabled };
    },
    dispatch => ({
      methodOne: () => dispatch(actions.methodOne()),
      methodTwo: () => dispatch(actions.methodTwo())
    })
)(TestComponent);
```

**package.json**

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-dom": "16.8.6",
"react-test-renderer": "16.8.6",
"redux-mock-store": "1.5.4",
"jest": "24.8.0",
"enzyme": "3.11.0"
```

So, I tried using `.dive()` but that didn't work for me. I tried different ways to achieve. But either the error is given that I need to wrap it with `<Provider>` and provide store, or when I used dive, it gave me an error that it can only be used on components. Currently, I'm getting the following error,

```
   expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality
   Expected: true
   Received: false
```

Please help me resolve this issue. I'm newbie to writing unit test cases for react-redux (connected components) in enzyme or jest. Any references will be highly appreciated. TIA.